# Set interval not working after bullet navigation is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created my own slider and now I am facing an issue with calling the auto sliding set interval function again after I used the bullet navigation. "setTimeout(autoSlide, 1000);" is not working. The code I have tried is given below. Please do get me a solution. Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title> Custom Slider </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .slide
        {
            float: left;
            width: 960px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: #000;
        }
        .slide h1
        {
            color: #fff;
        }
        #container
        {
            width: 960px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        #wrapper
        {
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
        }
        #bullets li
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 4</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol id="bullets">
    </ol>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var slideWidth = $('.slide').width();
            var slideLength = $('.slide').length;
            var totalWidth = slideWidth * slideLength;
            $('#wrapper').css('width', totalWidth);
            var currentPos = $('#wrapper').position().right;
            var currentIndex = 0;
            var autoSlide;
            function auto(){
                currentIndex += 1;
                if(currentIndex > slideLength - 1)
                {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                $('#wrapper').animate({right: currentIndex * slideWidth});
            }

            var autoSlide = setInterval(auto, 1000);
            $('.slide').each(function(){
                $('#bullets').append('<li class="bullet"> </li>');
            });

            $('.bullet').click(function(){
                clearInterval(autoSlide);
                var bulletIndex = $(this).index();
                if(bulletIndex > slideLength - 1)
                {
                    bulletIndex = 0;
                }           
                $('#wrapper').animate({right: bulletIndex * slideWidth});       
                currentIndex = bulletIndex;
                setTimeout(autoSlide, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "is not working"? What happens? What *doesn't* happen? Are there errors? Why `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`?

Comment: When the page is loaded auto sliding is working. Then when I click on the bullets it is also working. But after I click on the bullet navigation the auto sliding is not initiating again. It stops. This is the only issue.How shall I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout(autoSlide, 1000);
```

is passing an old timer handle into `setInterval`, which won't work. Pass the function again:

```
autoSlide = setTimeout(auto, 1000);
```

Also note that `setTimeout` will set up a timer that only fires *once*, whereas your original `setInterval` will set up a *repeating* timer, so you may have wanted `setInterval` there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now its working if I use setInterval again `autoSlide = setInterval(auto, 1000);`. But I need ti set a delay of 2 seconds and then start auto sliding. What shall I do?

Comment: @Kowshikan: Just delay the restart by two seconds: `setTimeout(function() { autoSlide = setInterval(auto, 1000); }, 2000);` Note that with that, there will be a two-second delay before we restart the interval timer, than another one-second delay before that interval timer fires for the first time, giving us a total of three seconds. If you want a total of two, delay the restart by just one second rather than two.

Comment: cool. Its working when "I click once, wait for the auto slide and click again". But when I continuously click three or four bullets with out gap and wait. The auto slide speeds up with irregular interval with the same speed I clicked the bulltets. What might be the issue?

Comment: @Kowshikan: Sounds like overlapping timers that you need to manage (much as with the managing of timers we're already doing above). But that's a *different* question.